# Piecewise and Opacity

Tags: plotting

I have the following Plot :

```
Plot[Cos[theta], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02],ColorFunction -> (Opacity[Evaluate[#], Red] &),AxesLabel ->{\[Theta], Energie}, Ticks -> {{0, Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1, 0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Here the opacity of the cosinus increases as a function of theta. Is there a way to do the following thing :

- opacity is equal to 1 (or a function of theta) over the interval [0,Pi[
- opacity is equal to 0 (or a function of theta) over the interval [Pi,2Pi]

It is like the function "Piecewise" but for the opacity but I think I can't use this one for my problem.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Geoffroy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit:* As suggested by J.M. here's an alternative solution

```
Plot[Cos[θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], AxesLabel -> {"θ", "Energie"}, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x}, RGBColor[1, 0, 0, If[0 <= x <= π, 1, 0.2]]], 
     Ticks -> {{0, π, 2 π}, {-1, 0, 1}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Cos[θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], AxesLabel -> {"θ", "Energie"}, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x}, Piecewise[{{Opacity[1, Red], 0 <= x <= π}, 
               {Opacity[.2, Red], π < x <= 2 π}}]], 
     Ticks -> {{0, π, 2 π}, {-1, 0, 1}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate Q, but can't find it ..

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: The alpha channel of `RGBColor[]` can also be manipulated directly: `Function[x, RGBColor[1, 0, 0, If[0 <= x <= π, 1, 0.2]]]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Correct, Why not add it as an answer ?

Comment: I *still* don't have a computer, and this is one of those answers that need a picture to go along with it. For now, I'd be alright with you adding it as an addendum to your answer.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Done and thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `MeshShading`:

```
Plot[Cos[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], 
 Ticks -> {{0, Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1, 0, 1}}, MeshFunctions -> (#1 &), 
 Mesh -> {{Pi}}, MeshShading -> {Red, Opacity[0.2, Red]}, 
 MeshStyle -> None]
```

[image]